# WP Query - Outputting JSON and normal loop of posts

Tags: wp-query

I have a normal WP query that will output to JSON to fill out Google maps location data after search. What I'm trying to do next is also output the `posts` with title/thumbnail/link beside the map with the same query. How can I use the same query to output 2 variables - `JSON = $locations` and normal post output `$postloop`?

Function

```
<?php
function my_search(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => $_POST['date'],
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after' => $_POST['property_added']
            ),
        ),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($query->have_posts()){
        while($query->have_posts()){
            $query->the_post();

            $locations[] = array(
                "name" => get_the_title(),
                "lat" => get_field('loc_lat'),
                "lng" => get_field('loc_lng')

            );
        }
    }
    //Return the data as JSON
    echo json_encode( $locations);
    die();

    //**Return normal query here to show post title/thumbnail excerpt etc **

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_search', 'my_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_search', 'my_search' );
```

**UPDATE 1**

**Ajax.js**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();//preventing form to submit with page reload
        var filter = $('#filter');

        $.ajax({
            url: filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(),
            async:false,
            type: 'POST', // POST
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#response').html(response.posts);
                showCloseLocations(response.data);
                
             };
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**WP QUERY**

```
$posts =  ‘#the post query output for posts’;
$locationmap = json_encode( $locations );
$response = array(‘posts’=>$posts, 'data'=>$locationmap);
echo json_encode($response);
die();
```

**JSON OUTPUT**

```
{html: "#the post query output for posts", data: "[{\"name\":\"Test property\"…e\",\"lat\":\"xx.xxxxxx\",\"lng\":\"-x.xxxxxxxxxxx\"}]"}
```

The JSON should be outputting as this:

```
[{name: "Test property", lat: "x.xxxxxxxx", lng: "-x.xxxxxxxx"}, {name: "Property 3", lat: "xx.xxxxxxxx", lng: "-x.xxxxxxxx"}]
```

Comment: The REST endpoint in your last question didn't help? By the way why can't you do this? You are already outputting the post's title.

Comment: I suppose I could include the title, link and thumbnail within the endpoint but worried for larger JSON responses this could cause unnecessary load. Id like to be able to individually output the JSON to `$locations` and the other to output the custom posts with title/link/thumbnail etc.

Comment: Once you run the query, it doesn't matter if you include title/thumbnail or not. WordPress already did the heavy task of querying the database, so the primary load is lifted.

Comment: Good point! I'll just do that then I think. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: You're welcome. I actually had some similar question like this, you may find it useful in [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/253991/94498).

Comment: @JackJohansson hey, could you take a look at `Update 1` in the question please? My thought process is to output both variables `$posts` for the posts that display on `response` div and `$locationmap` as the JSON data that dumps into the map js. I understand the endpoint method would be better but need to trigger the Ajax button to filter the query and success back to output JSON into map and normal post titles/images into `response` div. The problem is I can't seem to split `data` and `posts` from the array.

Comment: @JackJohansson If I test by adding some sample html to the `$posts` variable it will output fine but the JSON data `response.data` doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: That's because you have more than one JSON output. For example, you need to do something like `response.data[0]` to access the first output. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6842909) answer might help you.